# Best Windows Application which support both ssh and sftp

Tags: ssh, sftp, putty, windows, winscp

I am looking for applications that support both ssh and sftp (file transfer) protocols, Something like combination of putty and WinSCP. I know one: [MobaXterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/), but it is buggy and very slow compare to WinSCP and putty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Xshell4 (http://www.netsarang.com/products/xsh_overview.html) with Xftp4. I used Xshell for 3 years. It is free for home and school use

Comment: How can I use both ssh and sftp at the same time on this application?

Comment: When you ssh using xshell, xftp will add an icon in shell toolbar. Once you click there, you will have the sftp connection to same server. http://www.netsarang.com/faq/xshell/list- FAQ8 is what you are looking for.